# .htaccess rewriteCondition for one special directory while all other requests go through

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to mod_rewrite. My problem: I have two rules colliding with each other.

In my doc root I used to have only one .htaccess redirecting all incoming requests to a fast-cgi script like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fcgi-bin/python-script.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I have a folder with php scripts in my doc root let's call it "specialdir". How can I redirect requests from `www.mydomain.com/special` to the php `specialfolder` while having the rest of the requests still sent to the fcgi script?

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^special$ specialfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
```

But the request is obviously still handled by my "catch all" `^(.*)$` directive.

Should I include some kind of condition? How would it have to look?

**EDIT**: My full .htaccess file

```
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


AuthType Basic
AuthName "login"
AuthUserFile /var/www/v/htuser
Require valid-user

#php rewrite
RewriteRule ^special/(.*) specialfolder/$1 [QSA,L]

#trac rewrite
RewriteRule ^trac(.*)$ fcgi-bin/trac-proj/$1 [QSA,L]

#django rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ fcgi-bin/django/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^media/(.*)$ fcgi-bin/django/media/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules are applied in the order they are listed in the .htaccess file.  If you move the second rule up above the first rule, it will take precedence.

However, the second rule has other problems.  By "bookending" your regex with `^` and `$` you will only match `special` exactly, `special/` will not be matched and neither will `special/foobar`.

Also, the replacement part contains `$1` which will be replaced by whatever was matched inside the parentheses.  Since you have no parentheses in your pattern, the `$1` in the replacement is confusing.

What you probably want is this:

```
RewriteRule ^special/(.*) specialfolder/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And make sure it is above the previously mentioned rewrite in the file.

Comment: THX but this produces the same result. The rule first mentioned still takes precedence. Even though placed behind.

Comment: Could you add the entire current .htaccess to your question?

Comment: Added the whole file.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem.  The `RewriteCond` at the very top applies to the next `RewriteRule`, no matter how far down the file it may be.  If the URI starting with `special/` actually matches a file in the `special/` directory then the rewrite that makes it work will be ignored.  Either put the `RewriteCond` in the correct place or comment it out.

Comment: Couldn't make it work... I moved the "special" folder to another location and created a subdomain. in this case it was the cleaner solution. thx for your help anyways!